# ActionScript: How to start something that has a method: .stop( );

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright, so I'm making this little game in ActionScript using Flash Builder. The duck asset has an animation. I used `duck.stop();` to stop the Movie Clip so the animation doesn't play.

However, when I click on the duck, I need to figure out a way to once against start the Movie Clip. Does anyone know a way I could go about doing this?

```
    private function makeDucks(amount:uint):void
    {
        for(var j:int = 0; j < amount; j++){
            var duck:Duck = new Duck();
            addChild(duck);

        duck.x = j * (duck.width + duck.width / 3);

        // .stop stops the MovieClip
        duck.stop();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
duck.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onDuckClicked);

private function onDuckClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var duck:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    if(duck)
        duck.play();
}
```